# Logical Values in SQL SELECT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, logic

I would like to ultimately write a query that would return the "truth table" result of various LHS *operand* RHS logical operations.  I would expect to see a final result looking something like

| LHS | op | RHS | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | > | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | > | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | > | Null | Null |
| 1 | > | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | > | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | > | Null | Null |
| Null | > | 0 | Null |
| Null | > | 1 | Null |
| Null | > | Null | Null |
| 0 | <= | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | <= | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | <= | Null | Null |
| 1 | <= | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | <= | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | <= | Null | Null |
| Null | <= | 0 | Null |
| Null | <= | 1 | Null |
| Null | <= | Null | Null |
| 0 | <> | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | <> | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | <> | Null | Null |
| 1 | <> | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | <> | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | <> | Null | Null |
| Null | <> | 0 | Null |
| Null | <> | 1 | Null |
| Null | <> | Null | Null |

I was initially stymied in this quest by not being able to simply return a True/False or 1/0 from a simple `select` statement.  If, for instance, I wish to return the truth table result (`1` or `True`) of `1>0`, I cannot simply
`SELECT 1>0`, but instead have to do something akin to

```
SELECT
    1 LHS, '>' op, 0 RHS,
    CASE WHEN (1>0) -- replace 1>0 with logical check of choice 
            THEN 1
         WHEN NOT (1>0) -- remember to do so here also
            THEN 0
            ELSE NULL
    END result
```

, or the equivalent IIF statement; both the CASE and IIF solutions would require the equation twice - first directly, then within a NOT negation to check for NULL values as possible returns.

Generalizing this to LHS and RHS, we have

```
SELECT 
    A.LHS, A.op, A.RHS,
    CASE WHEN (A.LHS>A.RHS) -- replace LHS>RHS with logical check of choice 
            THEN 1
         WHEN NOT (A.LHS>A.RHS) -- remember to do so here also
            THEN 0
            ELSE NULL
    END
FROM
    Value_Table A
```

Setting the operator value is something that I also haven't figured out as the operators themselves have to be (AFAIK) stored as strings, so

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (A.LHS A.op A.RHS)
            THEN 1
         WHEN NOT (A.LHS A.op A.RHS)
            THEN 0
            ELSE NULL
    END
FROM
    Value_plus_Op_Table A
```

obviously won't work.

Doing

```
SELECT 
    CASE A.op
         WHEN '>'
           THEN CASE
              WHEN (A.LHS > A.RHS)
              THEN 1
           WHEN NOT (A.LHS > A.RHS)
              THEN 0
              ELSE NULL
           END
         WHEN '<='
           THEN CASE
              WHEN (A.LHS <= A.RHS)
              THEN 1
           WHEN NOT (A.LHS <= A.RHS)
              THEN 0
              ELSE NULL
         END END result
FROM
    Value_plus_Op_Table A
```

is not a general solution, as each op code must be changed to the appropriate context on an individual basis.

On this server I DO have access to do `sp_executesql`, but I can't simply `sp_executesql @statement=CAST(A.LHS as NVarchar(50))+' '+A.op+' '+(A.RHS as NVarchar(20))` and expand that in the two places in the code that `LHS op RHS` appears, but would instead need to build the whole query into a string and execute that; and I'm not sure how I would execute that for a list of operands in a single query.

So, how can this query be generalized to encompass multiple operands and data types?

Comment: What would you expect `select 1 || 1 ` to return? SQL Server has no `boolean` data type. You need to use a `CASE` expression (or the `IIF` function, which is a shorthand `CASE`) and *explicitly* define what values you want when the condition is true (and optionally false).

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Your `CASE` doesn't make sense. `num.one>num.one` can **never** be true. A value can never be greater (and not equal) to itself. I assume you would *actually* want `CASE WHEN one > zero THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` or `IIF(one > zero,1,0)`

Comment: that is the point.  I want values returned based on a comparison between values.  here i was checking 1>1, which is obviously FALSE.

Comment: Sql doesn't use `||`, it uses `or`. It doesn't use `&&`, it uses `and`. It doesn't use `!`, it uses `not`. So, `select 1 or 1`. But then see Larnu's comment. The result of `1 or 1` is boolean. The query will certainly honour boolean results (or actually, 3-valued-logic results) *in predicates* (like `where` clauses, `case` expressions, `join`, etc). But if you want to get an actual result out of the engine, you have to tell it how that result should be produced: `select iif(1 = 1, 1, 0)`. Or `select iif(1 = 1, 'true', 'false')`. Etc

Comment: *" I want values returned based on a comparison between values."* But you aren't comparing value***s***, you are comparing a value (singular) to itself.

Comment: replace with num.one<num.zero then

Comment: @Larnu ...which is a perfectly legal thing to do and will produce a 3vl result. But this is all a red-herring unrelated to the actual question.

Comment: Basically, I want to generate a truth table of various logical operators.  I'm using 1 as a standard stand-in for TRUE.

Comment: Right, so use `iif()` or `case`, and provide the output value you want depending upon the 3vl result.

Comment: It's *legal* but it's not logical, @allmhuran , and neither is a value (singular) values (plural). My point in that comment is that the OP in one breath said thety want to compare values (plural) but then in the comparison they compare a value (singular); comparing a value (singular) to itself is *not* comparing values (plural) to one another.

Comment: @Larnu they are comparing two values. One is the value on the left side of the operator, the other is the value on the right. Those values happen to be identical. Again, this is a red-herring that is just polluting the comments.

Comment: It's not that they are identical (2 different columns with the same value), `num.one>num.one` is the *same* value, @allmhuran . It is the same column; hence it doesn't make any logical sense. yes, it's all a red herring, but it's all a red herring because what the OP is describing doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @Larnu There's nothing illogical or incoherent about comparing a value with itself. It's *unnecesary*. It's *pointless*. But it's perfectly *logical*.

Comment: This feels an awful lot like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: It appears we disagree then, @allmhuran . If i ever saw a query with `WHERE A.ID > A.ID` I would flag that query as flawed, *every single time*, because the `WHERE` is *not* logical, and it would never return a result set contained rows. *Never*.

Comment: @Larnu Perhaps I didn't set up my question correctly, but the whole point of this is to show the result of a logical operation. Would it make sense to compare A.value > B.value where the value in A happens to be 1 and the value in B also happens to be 1? What if a different set of values are used?

Comment: _show the result of a logical operation_ You need to define what that means in the context of a SQL query. There are specific datatypes involved and your assumptions are not helpful. As noted already, there is no boolean datatype but we should not confuse that with bit - which is a numeric type. We have operators that work with different datatypes (using the implicit conversion if they are different from each other or different from what the operator expects). Don't try to use SQL like you might some other language.

Comment: The short of it is to use a `CASE`/`IIF` if you want a "Boolean" result in the `SELECT`, @mpag . Honestly if youwere to edit this question to provide what you actually want, with sample data and expected results we can help you better.

Comment: edited significantly.  I put in a nicely formatted table of my expected results, but I get the following error unless I put the table in a codeblock (as I have done). `Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon. `  Can a mod override that error?

Comment: If your goal is to create a table in a database with `{LHS, OP, RHS}` as columns, and run T-SQL to generate the `result` column, then you can do it with a cursor and dynamic SQL, or you could use a giant `case` as per your "not general" solution. But it's still not clear exactly what the point of the question is. If you're asking "is this possible in T-SQL", the answer is yes. If you're asking "why isn't SQL as a language designed to make dynamic expression-stored-as-text evaluation easy", the only coherent answer is tautological: It's not what the language is designed for.

Comment: This reminds me of a business rules engine, except you should be pulling rules into an app to run them, not the database-- at least not at the batch level. Maybe in a stored proc where you're working with data that eventually upserts into a table. [though these rules already live in the context of app code languages.]

Comment: @ps2goat If I understand you correctly, that would use the app code language's comparison operators.  I had hoped to expose the action of the operators within SQL, in all their various quirks.  So, `==` shouldn't work for comparison nor should `!=` AFAIK. I think I'll just heed @allmhuran's implied advice and not spend more time trying to do something SQL isn't designed to do.